# gmail login integration in android using oauth without google plus

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, gmail, google-plus, google-oauth

I already done for Google plus login oauth webview integration in my android application. but, here had one problem.

suppose one user created a new gmail account. he did not use or click Google plus login.
at that time, that new user will come and login in my application means,

how can i get user email and profile information. 
please any one help me.

note : here important is , user not used or logged or clicked or used google plus login

this is my prevoius question. just for ref:
[how to get email address using this scope from google plus integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057215/how-to-get-email-address-using-this-scope-from-google-plus-integration)

Answer (score 1):

So I have an account with plus actually disabled without the user ever clicking plus service.  I was able to use the "email" scope to get the email address of my user.

The scope is literally just "email" instead or URI.  More details here:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

And here are the responses that I get:

Request:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

Response:

{
  "kind": "plus#person", 
  "displayName": "", 
  "name": {
    "givenName": "", 
    "familyName": ""
  }, 
  "isPlusUser": false, 
  "image": {
    "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50", 
    "isDefault": true
  }, 
  "domain": "mytestdomain.com", 
  "emails": [
    {
      "type": "account", 
      "value": "emily@mytestdomain.com"
    }
  ], 
  "id": "1xxxxxxx621233395686", 
  "objectType": "person"
}

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Emily,this is somewhat ok.but,before this process.i need to do get secret id from api console..ie I did not have secret id. i have only client id in android. how do oauth2 in android.

Comment: some sample code..String googleAuthorizationRequestUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(Credential.CLIENT_ID, Credential.REDIRECT_URI, Credential.SCOPE).build();
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

Comment: public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith(Credential.REDIRECT_URI)) {
     try {
      if (url.indexOf("code=") != -1) {
       String code = url.substring(Credential.REDIRECT_URI.length() + 7, url.length());
       AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), Credential.CLIENT_ID, null, code, Credential.REDIRECT_URI).execute();

Comment: I think the sample code is for web application.  When you create a credential for webapp in API console, it provides both client ID and secret. For android, here is a doc: http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html that explains further.